# C# Enumerable over a type gives different options (Finding more options in a function)

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, caliburn.micro, ienumerator

What cast or library am I missing to import in the code snippet below? I would like to be able to convert the bytes to arrays.

Example:

1. A.interface=> gives four values at one location
   vertices.=>values has only four options to choose from
2. A.interface=> gives 30 values at another location.
   whereas in another class, I have multiple options to be selected.

   public static byte[] GetRGB32Pixels(SampleImage image, out int cwidth, out int cheight)
   {
   Sample.imagedatacdata;
   byte[] cpixels = null;
   cwidth = cheight = 0;
   if (image.AcquireAccess(Sample.Imageaccess.ACCESS_READ, Sample.PixelFormat.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB32, out cdata) >= Sample.Status.STATUS_NO_ERROR)
      {
        cwidth = (int)cdata.pitches[0] / sizeof(Int32);
        cheight = (int)image.Info.height;
        cpixels = cdata.ToByteArray(0, (int)cdata.pitches[0] * cheight);
        image.ReleaseAccess(cdata);
                   }
         return cpixels;
               }

Can you help me understand? In the above code, I am referring to the SampleImage datatype. If I extend SampleImage instance "image" within the code I am getting only limited options but in another class when I call the same instance of SampleImage I am seeing multiple options.

Comment: Linq - `using System.Linq;` provides about 30 *extension methods* for the `IEnumerable<T>`. It seems you have the `using` in one place and doesn't have in another

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for your comments David. please make sure if this meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `using System.Linq` in the file where you have the extra options. This using brings in several extension methods that help with LINQ (see details on extensions methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods))